# Jquery Autocomplete not passing the selected value to the Partial View

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to implement a jquery autocomplete input textbox. The selected value is passed to a Partial View when a button is clicked, but it's not working. The selected value is not being passed to the controller to be rendered in the partial View. I want to know how can I perform this.

This is my view code:

```
 <label class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 control-label" for="Teste">Aeroporto:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <input id="aeroportoAutocomplete" type="text" class="form-control" name="AeroportoNome" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <input id="continuarBtn" type="button" value="Continuar" class="btn btn-primary"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br />

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div id="formularioPesquisa">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the autocomplete javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#aeroportoAutocomplete").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/DemandaAgregada/AeroportoAutocomplete",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { termo: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.OACI + " - " + item.AEROPORTO,
                                value: item.OACI + " - " + item.AEROPORTO
                            };
                        }))
                    }
                })
            },
            messages: {
                noResult: "",
                results: ""
            },
        });
    })
</script>
```

Here is the script that is used with the controller to render the Partial View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#continuarBtn').click(function () {
            $.get('@Url.Action("FormularioPesquisa", "DemandaAgregada")', function (data) {
                $('#formularioPesquisa').replaceWith(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Finally, here is my controller methods that perform the autocomplete and that render the partial view:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AeroportoAutocomplete(string termo)
    {
        var aeroportoDimensao = horaPicoDB.AeroportoDimensao;

        var aeroportos = (from aero in aeroportoDimensao
                          where aero.OACI.ToLower().Contains(termo.ToLower()) ||
                          aero.IATA.ToLower().Contains(termo.ToLower()) ||
                          aero.AEROPORTO.ToLower().Contains(termo.ToLower()) ||
                          aero.CIDADE.ToLower().Contains(termo.ToLower())
                          select new 
                          { 
                              aero.OACI,
                              aero.AEROPORTO
                          }).ToList();

        return Json(aeroportos, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public ActionResult FormularioPesquisa(string AeroportoNome)
    {

        ViewBag.Message = "Aeroporto Nome: " + AeroportoOACI;

        return PartialView("FormPesquisaDemAgregada");
    }
```

Comment: Your code will not even compile because you are using `AeroportoOACI` which is not defined anywhere!!! Also where is the code which reads the selected value of the auto complete and send that to the server via the ajax call ?

Comment: Sorry I just corrected that mistake!!! I did this code based on an example and the code was just like that (it's my first time dealing with jquery). Do I have to define a **request.term** to pass the selected value to the controller??

Comment: `$.get('@Url.Action("FormularioPesquisa", "DemandaAgregada")', { AeroportoNome: "replace this with selected" }, function (data) {`